# Altium Draftsman Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: altium, error

I am trying to create a Draftsman template that includes the parameter names, view locations, etc already built-in. This way when I set the Draftsman drawing template, the views are automatically populated. Altium claims this can be done by editing the DwfDot template file. I created a drawing based on an actual board and set the locations of all the views, and also created the parameters I wanted. I then saved the file as a DwfDot. When I set the template of the Draftsman document for a different board, the views are populated as expected but the parameters have problems. Some of the parameters don't "stick" (I set them but when I close the parameter dialog they are automatically cleared). I re-opened the DwfDot template file for editing and now when I try to edit the parameters I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

[image]

So at this point I'm stuck -- trying to add the value for the parameter in my actual drawing does not work as it automatically clears when I exit the parameters window, and I am unable to edit the template because of the object reference error. What is the cause of this error, and how might it be resolved?

**EDIT:**

I managed to solve the problem with the parameters being automatically cleared. It turns out I had some parameter names in my document that matched the names of some of the project parameters. When I added the parameter to the project options parameter dialog, the field in the Draftsman document filled in. To combat this issue I simply prefaced all document parameter names (that I only wanted visible in the Draftsman documents) with "Doc" and adjusted the document parameters to reflect the change. For example, "Title" is a system project parameter, and I had a document-specific "Title" parameter. The system project parameter was overriding the value I placed in the document "Title" parameter. I changed the Draftsman template so that instead of showing "=Title" it now shows "=DocTitle", and added "DocTitle" as a document parameter, and this is working perfectly. Unfortunately the other issue I mentioned still exists, and that is I can't seem to clear parameters in the template created from another document.